# Problems with CSS @import url() on port 8080

Tags: css, url, import, port

My machine is listening on port 8080.

The site outputs the following rel tag to the browser:

```
<rel type="stylesheet" href="/path/to/loader.css" media="screen">
```

The loader.css outputs:

```
@import url(this.css);
@import url(that.css);
```

This works in FireFox and Chrome on port 80. But not on port 8080.

Should it not?

Comment: @import is not very frequently used (better to use it with SASS/Less where it gets concatenated before the user sees it). Because it's infrequently used, you may find people haven't seen this behaviour before.

Comment: Is it trying to load the files from port 80 instead?

Comment: use a relative or absolute URL instead ie `@import url("/path/to/this.css");`

Comment: I discovered it did load the first css (this.css) but not the second line (that.css). Could this be the EOL format?

Comment: It is working now. Rewrote the loader.css. Must have been an illegal byte character somewhere or something. The example in the question works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The example in the question works fine. Check for syntax errors or corrupted byte data.